# cursor position when page refresh

Tags: asp.net

in my web application i have 12 textboxes and 3 dropdown controls. dropdown control has the ispostback true, so when i select dropdown box page postback and it comes top of the application again i have to scroll down, my cursor remain in the same position after postback.
i think u understand my problem. please help.

Comment: No IsPostBack Property, it's AutoPostBack

Comment: If the answer solved your question then it would be nice to mark it as accepted answer. You haven't accepted any of the answers for your 20 questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the option to maintain the scroll position on postbacks per page or in the webconfig for all pages..

Webconfig:

```
<pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" />
```

Per Page:

```
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

or

```
Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
```